# Maven uses only central repository with Nexus

Tags: maven, nexus

I've set up Nexus to proxy the central Maven repository and added a mirror to `settings.xml`:

```xml
<mirror>
    <id>nexus</id>
    <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    <url>http://my-host:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/</url>
</mirror>
```

It works fine but if I try to add additional repositories to `pom.xml` like this:

```xml
<repository>
    <id>jboss</id>
    <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
</repository>
```

Maven just doesn't see those repositories, until I remove `<mirror>` from `setting.xml`. I've also tried to mirror other repositories to Nexus, with no luck: Maven still uses only the central repository.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a whole two ways to solve the problem.

By using profiles: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html

Or by using grouping in Nexus: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-managing-groups.html

Seems it's helpful to read the documentation before asking questions:)